# Why didn't Michonne kill the Governor?

Tags: the-walking-dead

On the Walking Dead (the Graphic Novel, not the TV Series), right before Glenn, Rick and Michnone leave Woodbury, Michonne goes back and tortures the Governor.

Why didn't she kill him? She must have known that if he survived he was going to (try to) kill them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She wanted him to suffer.  She made a point of telling him how she was going to prolong his agony before killing him.

[image: Michonne describes what is in store for the Governor]

However, I believe she was interrupted by the Governor's henchmen arriving at the door.

While she could have taken a couple of extra seconds to ensure that he was dead before she left, Michonne had been living on her own (if you don't count her two walker "companions"), and had a *very* finely-honed survival instinct.  I don't think its a stretch to imagine that she'd react *instantly* the moment she heard reinforcements arrive, without taking the time to finish the Governor off.  For someone who has lived out in the wild, on her own, as long as she has, self-preservation would likely outweigh vengeance, no matter how badly she wanted revenge.

Besides, as was already pointed out, she probably believed there was a very good chance he'd die from his wounds.  She'd also had plenty of time to work him over, in a variety of horrific ways.

It is possible that she even considered that the longer he lived in the state she'd left him in, the more complete her revenge would be.

She didn't want to kill him.  She wanted to **hurt** him, to repay him for what he did to her.  The dead feel no pain.

Answer (score 0):

She came, she made sure he had a fatal wound and then she left him coz she probly realised that she is better than him.

(Him beeing a psychopat killer and all)